# How to retrieve implemented class of interface having generic parameter in Java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

**Sample Code Structure**

```
class Param1{}

class Param2{}

interface Generic<T>{}

class Impl1 implements Generic<Param1>{}

class Imp2 implements Generic<Param2>{}
```

I want to retrieve implemented class using Generic Param and Interface (Param1.class,Generic.class - > Impl1.class)
Any libraries are appreciated ?

Comment: I do not know about any existing libraries, but you can achieve the same using a HashMap. where Param1 and Param could be key and would return the correcponding Impl1 and Impl2 as values

Comment: That will work, but we want to do it in straight way

Comment: You description is too simple. How many implementation of `Generic` we know? Where can we find them? If there are only `Impl1` and `Impl2`, you can check the generic type directly to determine which is implementation of `Generic<Param1>`.